# How can I make ECR private repo public?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecr, repo

I created a ECR repo which is private. Now i want to make it public with all containers. Is there any way i can make it public from private. i mean is there any flag which can make it public. i dont want to create new repo and make it public and push all containers ?

Answer (score 3):

It's stated in ECR that you can't change its visibility

> Once a repository is created, the visibility setting of the repository can't be changed.

However, you can [allow other account to push/pull ECR image from your account](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/secondary-account-access-ecr/).

If that's too much of a burden for you. Maybe creating new public repo is not a bad choice.